# Implementing pagination in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I wish to implement pagination in my search results in the view page. Currently in the controller, I limit it to 10 results to view. How do I implement pagination?

In my controller,

```
var $name = 'Searches';
var $components = array('Auth');
var $uses = array('User','Passion');
$users = $this->User->find('all',array('limit'=>10,'conditions'=>$final_conditions,'fields'=>array('User.*')));
```

In my view page,

```
    <?php foreach ($search_fields as $user): ?> 
        <tr>
            <?php //debug($search_fields);?>
            <td><?php echo $user['User']['firstName']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user['User']['lastName']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user['User']['email']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user['User']['displayName']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $user['User']['gender']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Please read the Cookbook: http://book.cakephp.org/view/164/Pagination . But why do you use cakephp 1.2?

Comment: The Cookbook covers pagination quite extensively. Do you have a specific problem implementing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller

```
$this->paginate = array(
'conditions' => $final_conditions,
'limit' => 10
);

$users = $this->paginate('User');
```

In the view you just use the same as on http://book.cakephp.org/view/166/Pagination-in-Views